# Transfer an angular 4 project from Win 10 in macOS

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a project in win 10 that works fine.
@angular/core 4.2.6 + firebase 3
@angular/cli 1.2.1
node  6.9.4

I tried to transfer it to an macOS but nothing works.
I tried to update the project but angular version becomes 5...!
node is 8.0.0 on macOs!
every thing is different!

What is the best solution for this? how I can manage this fast moving/ different package upgrades?

Here is what I get in macOS using "ng new proj" before updating the project:

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 8.0.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/compiler-cli: 2.4.10
```

then I used this to upgrade to angular 4:

```
sudo npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@next --save
```

This point I get angular 5

```
angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3
node: 8.0.0
os: darwin x64
@angular/animations: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/common: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/compiler: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/core: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/forms: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/http: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/platform-browser: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/platform-server: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/router: 5.0.0-beta.0
@angular/compiler-cli: 5.0.0-beta.0
```

this is what original project has in win 10:

[image]

If i just copy the project folder to macOS and run it without any changes, I'll get this:

```
    The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Private' of undefined
Error: The "@angular/compiler-cli" package was not properly installed. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Private' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:14:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js:3:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-configs/index.js:9:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-config.js:4:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/serve.js:11:24)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/serve.run.js:6:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:513:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Class.run (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/serve.js:67:16)
    at Class.<anonymous> (/Users/username/.Trash/myForm 11.32.24 PM/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/command.js:134:17)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are moving project from one OS to another OS, I would not suggest to create it from start, reason being is, angular-cli keeps get updates very frequently.

So, Every time you install and create new project with `ng new PROJECTNAME` then you will always get latest version of all libraries (depending upon angular-cli version).

Solution:

- Create one github repository of your existing project
- Add,Commit and push your project code including `package.json` (which is responsible for maintaining versions)
- Clone and setup project at other environment (In your case on Mac OS)

You might have to execute similar kind of commands

```
$ npm install -g @angular/cli  (Note: If angular-cli is already installed then skip this step)
$ git clone CLONE REPO URL
$ cd PROJECTREPO
$ npm install
$ Run `ng serve` for a dev server.
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact I did this in first place, but it didn't work as usual. something changed today. Please verify my post, I have updated the result after doing what you suggested. I found some solutions to reinstall or update CLI but no results.

Answer (score 0):

Your version of angular Cli installed generally was outdated when you recreated your project. And before copying or recreating a new project uninstall angular-cli and node. Update your npm and install node and angular-cli. Do ng new and copy your project /app and /assets folders and index.html, style.css and so on. That should help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that:
to uninstall a CLI 1.0.0-beta.28 or less (my case), we need to run

```
npm uninstall -g angular-cli
npm uninstall --save-dev angular-cli
```

After that, I reinstalled latest CLI, globally and locally.

Many thanks to this [post](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli).